# Sentence improvement question

Tags: error

> Although the goal-keeper was responsible for the defeat in the important football match, nobody blamed him.

According to me it should be "yet nobody blamed him."

But the answer is no improvement. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 10):

There's no need for *yet* there—its sense is already expressed with *although*.

Comment: Sure, it would be superfluous but would that amount to a mistake? In Russian, e.g., either would be OK.

Comment: @MvLog  Yes, it would be considered a mistake in English.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include the word "yet" I suggest this:

> The goal-keeper was responsible for the defeat in the important
>   football match, yet nobody blamed him.

Your first sentence was good, without using "yet".

However, both sentences seem contradictory to me, because you *do* appear to blame the goal-keeper!

Comment: It is possible to be responsible for something yet not to blame.  He didn't catch the ball and it smashed the window (responsible) although he was was tied to a chair at the time. (but has a really good excuse so not to blame). Ok this is a really bad example but is the best i could come up with just before bedtime.

Comment: The confusion of "blame" and "responsibility" is one of the pervasive ills of our society. "Blame" is a wholly destructive addictive behaviour which gives its "fix" by letting the blamer avoid taking any  responsibility. </rant>

Comment: That contradiction is the point of the sentence.  The author is of the opinion that the goalkeeper was responsible, (s)he then makes the observation that nobody blamed him.  More context is needed, but I'd expect some sort of explanation later in the passage - it was a new or replacement goalie, there had been personal issues affecting him or he had just recovered from injury etc.